# When to use different implementations of Event Handlers in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, mouseevent

There is a Parent `Window` and a Child `UserControl` (assume a popup) which has multiple buttons. Those buttons use same `MouseEnter` & `MouseLeave` events.

I want to implement those mouse events in the `MainWindow` (parent). 
After some research, I found a few methods of achieving this.

In child UserControl `Control1.xaml` (Same in every method)

```
  <Button 
     x:Name = "TestButton1"
     MouseEnter = "TestButton_MouseEnter"
  \>

  <Button 
     x:Name = "TestButton2"
     MouseEnter = "TestButton_MouseEnter"
  \>
```

In `MainWindow.xaml` (Same in every method)

```
  <UserControl: Control1
     x:Name = "control1Popup"
  />
```

**Method 1:**

In child UserControl `Control1.xaml.cs`

```
Button focusedButton;
public static readonly RoutedEvent TestMouseEnterEvent
     = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("TestMouseEnter", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(MouseEventHandler), typeof(Button));

// expose Button mouse enter event
public event MouseEventHandler TestMouseEnter
{
    add { AddHandler(TestMouseEnterEvent, value); }
    remove { RemoveHandler(TestMouseEnterEvent, value); }
}

private void TestButton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    focusedButton = sender as Button;
    MouseEventArgs mouseEvent = new MouseEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0) { RoutedEvent = TestMouseEnterEvent};
    RaiseEvent(mouseEvent);
}
```

In `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
  //Constructor
  public MainWindow () {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.control1Popup.TestMouseEnter += (sender, e) => 
    {
       this.TestButton_MouseEnter (this.controlPopup.focusedButton, e);
    };
  }

  private void TestButton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    // Do action
  }
```

**Method 2:**

In child UserControl `Control1.xaml.cs`

```
  Button focusedButton;
  public event MouseEventHandler TestMouseEnter

  private void TestButton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    focusedButton = sender as Button;
    if (TestMouseEnter != null) 
    {
       TestMouseEnter (focusedButton, new MouseEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0));
    }
  }
```

In `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
  //Constructor
  public MainWindow () {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.control1Popup.TestMouseEnter += this.TestButton_MouseEnter;
  }

  private void TestButton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    // Do action
  }
```

**Method 3**

Without using those Event Handlers, I could be able to do this:

In `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
  //Constructor
  public MainWindow () {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.control1Popup.TestButton1.MouseEnter += this.TestButton_MouseEnter;
    this.control1Popup.TestButton2.MouseEnter += this.TestButton_MouseEnter;
  }
```

So, I am not sure in which method to use and would like further clarity on the matter.

Comment: What ? in third method you will still handle mouse events (enter and leave). And probably third way is better (lesser the code is always better).

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain but i still doubt about method 1 and 2 even method 3 is pretty easier to implement. Is there any situation that method 3 is not working?

Comment: It depends. But i see you are duplicating Mouse enter implementation in second method.

Comment: You need to implement `MOUSE_ENTER` only once in MAIN_WINDOW or It's own UC. Depending on your case. If you want to handle it in MainWindow then then Only the MainWindow's implementation is required.